# SNOWFLAKE : read a VARIANT column as a table?

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have the following table

```
WITH fake_data(columnA, columnB, columnC) as (
select * from values
(1, 'hello1', 'world18'),
(1, 'hello2', 'world27'),
(2, 'hello9', 'world36')
(3,  NULL, 'world35')
(10, 'hello13', 'world5')
```

)

We convert the entire table into a single column that has a JSON-like structure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE LISTE_JSON (V variant)
AS
WITH COLONNE_KEY
AS (
     SELECT
          ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY  columnA DESC) KEY_AUTO 
           ,A.*
     FROM fake_data A
),
COLONNE_OBJECT
AS (
   SELECT  
   object_agg(
              TO_CHAR(KEY_AUTO )  ,
                             object_construct(
                                            'columnA', IFNULL(columnA,''),
                                            'columnB', IFNULL(columnB,''),
                                            'columnC', IFNULL(columnC,''),
                                            )
            )AS  COLONNE_OBJECT                                

   FROM COLONNE_KEY                                                                            
)
SELECT *
FROM  COLONNE_OBJECT;
```

So far everything is going well.

Now how do I read the variant column through a SELECT and see it as a table, as it was at the beginning?

Ex:

```
SELECT *
FROM LISTE_JSON 

COLUMNA COLUMNB COLUMNC 
  1   hello1   world18
  1   hello2   world27
  2   hello9   world36
  3   ''       world35
  10  hello13  world5
```

Comment: Something like this should work - select to_number(value:"columnA") as columnA, 
value:"columnB" as columnB, 
value:"columnC" as columnC from
LISTE_JSON, table(flatten(input=>v)) 
order by columnA;

Comment: This is a bad question, not only do you not show the input to your question, you SQL to make the input does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ether use PIVOT to pull with parts, or you can hand roll the pivot via GROUP BY

```
SELECT 
  columna
  ,max(iff(columnb='hello1', columnc, null)) as hello1
  ,max(iff(columnb='hello2', columnc, null)) as hello2
  ,max(iff(columnb='hello3', columnc, null)) as hello3
from table
group by 1 order by 1;
```

So lets start with working "example code"

```
WITH fake_data(columnA, columnB, columnC) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 'hello1', 'world18'),
    (1, 'hello2', 'world27'),
    (2, 'hello9', 'world36'),
    (3,  NULL, 'world35'),
    (10, 'hello13', 'world5')
), COLONNE_KEY AS (
     SELECT
          ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY  columnA DESC) KEY_AUTO 
           ,A.*
     FROM fake_data A
), COLONNE_OBJECT AS (
   SELECT  
       object_agg( KEY_AUTO::text ,
                   object_construct('columnA', IFNULL(columnA::text,''), 
                                   'columnB', IFNULL(columnB::text,''), 
                                   'columnC', IFNULL(columnC::text,'')
                                   )
            )AS  COLONNE_OBJECT                                
   FROM COLONNE_KEY                                                                            
)
SELECT *
FROM  COLONNE_OBJECT;
```

gives:

| COLONNE_OBJECT |
| --- |
| { "1": { "columnA": "10", "columnB": "hello13", "columnC": "world5" }, "2": { "columnA": "3", "columnB": "", "columnC": "world35" }, "3": { "columnA": "2", "columnB": "hello9", "columnC": "world36" }, "4": { "columnA": "1", "columnB": "hello1", "columnC": "world18" }, "5": { "columnA": "1", "columnB": "hello2", "columnC": "world27" } } |

which you would like to get back into it original table form

thus

```
SELECT
    f.value:"columnA"::number as columna,
    f.value:"columnB"::text as columnb,
    f.value:"columnC"::text as columnc
FROM  COLONNE_OBJECT, table(flatten(input=>colonne_object)) f;
```

gives you back

| COLUMNA | COLUMNB | COLUMNC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | hello13 | world5 |
| 3 | <empty string> | world35 |
| 2 | hello9 | world36 |
| 1 | hello1 | world18 |
| 1 | hello2 | world27 |

and the `empty string` can be swapped back in via

```
nullif(f.value:"columnB"::text,'') as columnb,
```